# How can i validate left mouse click in a office window? (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application)

Tags: c#, vsto, office-interop, office-addins

I want to have a condition like below..Whenever user do left mouse click,then hyperlink should get fired. I am writing this condition as OfficeWindow.IsLeftClicked==MouseButtons.Left but it is not working.

```
    public static Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application App
    {
      get;
       set;
    }  
    App.WindowSelectionChange += new ApplicationEvents4_WindowSelectionChangeEventHandler(ApplicationWindowSelectionChange);                                           

    ApplicationWindowSelectionChange(Selection selection){
    if (OfficeWindow != null && OfficeWindow.IsLeftClicked==MouseButtons.Left)
    {
        OfficeWindow.Hyperlink(link, linkType, OfficeWindow.Context);
    }
```

Comment: What is `OfficeWindow` class? Is that a custom class? derives from any other class? and if you can provide the implementation of `OfficeWindow.IsLeftClicked`

Comment: Officewindow is just referring the current active window object